# comparing groups and getting equal values of all groups( pandas groupby)

Tags: pandas, group-by

i have a data frame which is

[image: data]
it has 3 years 2011 2012 and 2013 ,and 3 students a,b,c and their ranks in each year. i want to group by year and see which students have consistency we can see student b has rank 2 all over the years.

code I am using

```
 data=pd.DataFrame({'year': 
                [2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013],
               'student':['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'],
               'rank':[1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3]})
 grouped=data.groupby(['year'])
```

Comment: Don't post an image of the dataframe in question. Check -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: did what you have asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `Name` and check if their `rank` is the same value for all years and then get the `Name`s that satisfy that:

```
# `s.eq(s.iloc[0])` checks if all elements are the same as first
>>> res = df.groupby("name")["rank"].agg(lambda s: s.eq(s.iloc[0]).all())
>>> res

Name
a    False
b     True
c    False

# `res[res]` performs boolean masking to get only `True` rows
>>> res[res].index.tolist()
["b"]
```

---

If looking for a specific rank:

```
rnk = 3
res = df.groupby("Name")["rank"].agg(lambda s: s.eq(rnk).all())
res[res].index.tolist()
```

---

If need to ensure that ranked so in *all* possible years:

```
num_years = df.year.nunique()
rnk = 3
res = (df.groupby("Name")[["rank", "year"]]
         .apply(lambda s: s["rank"].eq(rnk).all()
                          and (s["year"].nunique() == num_years)))
res[res].index.tolist()
```

Comment: thanks but if i am intrested to find only rank 3 students can it be done like filtering based on rank ,

Comment: @sra Edited the answer for a specific rank, hope it helps.

Comment: aydin i have a issue with this code, if you don't mind I can share my original dataset from github so you can see the issue is it fine. the issue is if I have 4 records and 2 are matching it is considering it as true

Comment: you can acess here the dataset and the code I used https://github.com/sprabhala-cpu/stackoverflow

Comment: @sra Okay I think I see the issue. To assure that a particular `Name` (party there) has the rank 1 in *all* `Year`s, we need another condition. For the github data, modify the code as `res = df.groupby("Party")[["Position", "Election Year"]].agg(lambda s: s.Position.eq(1).all() and (s["Election Year"].nunique() == num_elections)).all(1)` where `num_elections = data1["Election Year"].nunique()`. This will also check if they ranked 1 in all possible elections. I also edited this answer with this way hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Pivot` the dataframe to `reshape`

```
table = data.pivot('student', 'year', 'rank')

# year     2011  2012  2013
# student                  
# a           1     3     1
# b           2     2     2
# c           3     1     3
```

To check for consistency of ranks for each student across multiple years, we can use `nunique` on `axis=1`

```
table.nunique(1).eq(1)

# student
# a    False
# b     True
# c    False
# dtype: bool
```

To check for consistency for a particular rank e.g. `3`, across multiple years

```
table.eq(3).all(1)

# student
# a    False
# b    False
# c    False
# dtype: bool
```